# Remove duplicates in Arrays from MYSQL query and then insert into another table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, duplicates

I have the code below to query a table which retrieves arrays.  The parameter $idList could have several values and may therefore produce duplicates.  I am only interested in inserting one unique memalertid.

Any advice on how to remove the duplicates would be much appreciated.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT  memalertid from memlist where listID IN ($idList) AND (emailyes = '1') ");
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$insert_query = "insert into subsalerts (memalertid, idMembers, emailid) VALUES('".$info['memalertid']."','$idMembers','$emailid')";
$insert_buffer = mysql_query($insert_query);
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `SELECT DISTINCT` to select distinct rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT memalertid FROM memlist WHERE listID IN ($idList) AND (emailyes = '1')
```

You could also `GROUP BY memalertid` instead.

```
SELECT memalertid FROM memlist WHERE listID IN ($idList) AND (emailyes = '1') GROUP BY memalertid
```

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
$newArray = array_unique($yourArray);
```

This will create a new array only with unique values; excluding any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) clause to group the results with the same id, so that you'll get only unique ids

Answer (score 0):

No need to get PHP involved. Just `SELECT` using `GROUP BY`.

```
INSERT INTO subsalerts (memalertid, idMembers, emailid)
    SELECT memalertid, $idMembers, $emailid FROM memlist WHERE listID IN ($idList) AND emailyes = 1 GROUP BY memalertid;
```